# Android MediaPlayer in background mode

Tags: android, service, media-player

I have a question about android MediaPlayer class
As I've seen that MediaPlayer by default continues to run when the user switches to background mode.

But what I have seen here [Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) .. They stated that if we want to make MediaPlayer plays in background, we must use Services.

I want to know why I should use services if it is already playing in background

Best regards

Comment: Activities can be destroyed and recreated, which means that if you manage the MediaPlayer in your Activity you'll have to retain the MediaPlayer somehow or you could end up leaking active MediaPlayer instances.

Comment: But Activities are not destroyed in background
They are just stopped or paused . so What is the uses of services in this case

Comment: They can be recreated even if they just have moved into the background: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: When does this case happen? .. can you please give me a case to test it

Answer (score 0):

Activities are very fickle, if android runs out of memory it will start to kill off backgrounded tasks/activities with onDestroy(). Once that method is called your mediaPlayer will be destroyed and will stop playing. Services, however, are given a higher priority than backgrounded activities and android will avoid destroying them for as long as it can, probably never.